# Get number of affected rows from mssql connection

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a script where I am required to use the `_mssql` module to `DELETE` and `UPDATE` tables on a **MSSQL 2005 Server**. (_mssql http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/ref__mssql.php)

```
con = _mssql.connect(server='SERVER', user='USER', password='PASSWORD', database='SOMETHING')

con.execute_query('DELETE [...]'
#print affected rows
con.execute_query('UPDATE [...]'
#print affected rows
```

I've come across a solution where I could use the `fetchall()` method of the cursor, but I do not have a cursor, only the connection to use.

Any ideas how to `print` the affected rows?

edit:

Despite the fact that `rows_affected` is described to be used with `SELECT` only, it seems to work for DELETE and UPDATE as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this from `con.rows_affected`. You will need to call it after each query since it returns the number of rows affected by the *last* query run.